# Java Resolve Response URLConnection Header Value

Tags: java, decode, urlconnection

I send http head request with URLConnection and got header value `Content-Disposition` Unreadable value like bellow.

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="à§©à¦Ÿà¦¿ à¦§à¦¾à¦ªà§‡ à¦¸à¦¹à¦œà§‡à¦‡ à¦†à¦¤à§à¦¬à¦¬à¦¿à¦¶à§à¦¬à¦¾à¦¸à§€ à¦¹à§Ÿà§‡ à¦‰à¦ à§à¦¨ | Motivational Video in Bangla.mp4"`

How to resolve this text `à§©à¦Ÿà¦¿ à¦§à¦¾à¦ªà§‡ à¦¸à¦¹à¦œà§‡à¦‡ à¦†à¦¤à§à¦¬à¦¬à¦¿à¦¶à§à¦¬à¦¾à¦¸à§€ à¦¹à§Ÿà§‡ à¦‰à¦ à§à¦¨` to `৩টি ধাপে সহজেই আত্ববিশ্বাসী হয়ে উঠুন`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the response comes in a.. non-typical, Bengali encoding. I couldn't find the exact one, but seems to be something close to "Windows-1252".

Running the below code gives me the following output, having issues with some composite characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    var source = "à§©à¦Ÿà¦¿ à¦§à¦¾à¦ªà§‡ à¦¸à¦¹à¦œà§‡à¦‡ à¦†à¦¤à§à¦¬à¦¬à¦¿à¦¶à§à¦¬à¦¾à¦¸à§€ à¦¹à§Ÿà§‡ à¦‰à¦ à§à¦¨";
    var bytes = source.getBytes("Windows-1252");
    System.out.println("Expected: " + "৩টি ধাপে সহজেই আত্ববিশ্বাসী হয়ে উঠুন");
    System.out.println("Actual  : " + new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

Expected: ৩টি ধাপে সহজেই আত্ববিশ্বাসী হয়ে উঠুন
Actual  : ৩টি ধাপে সহজেই আত�ববিশ�বাসী হয়ে উ� �ন
```

The solution may be to find the right decoder for this encoding of Bengali text so you can convert it to Unicode.
Best of luck!